# Tagulous - Displaying Posts based on filtering of self assigned tags

Tags: python, django, tags

I have created a posts list where users can simply create a post, upload a photo and similar to StackOverflow, they can assign "Tags" to their post to categorise their post (I am using Tagulous library to power the tags feature of my application)

At the moment users can assign tags to their Post. However, what I am wanting to achieve is the following:

- When a user creates a Post in a specific tag, I want to filter the overall Posts view, based on the past tags they have assigned to their previous posts. E.g. If User A assigns a tag called "Winter" to their Post, after submitting their post, they will see any other Posts on their Post Feed which are relevant to the "Winter" tag.

If in the future, they decide to assign one or more other tags to any future posts they create, those posts sharing the same tag name will also appear on their Post Feed.

In a nutshell, for every one tag which the user self assigns to any future post, they will begin to see Posts of other users who are using the same tag within their posts.

Where I am at, at the moment is:

- I have created a public Post View (A feed of where all my posts are displayed arranged by date order)
- I have created a view for where posts can be created and I have integrated Tagulous in to my Post Creation view.

Now, I am just trying to figure how to filter my posts based on which Tagulous tags the user has self assigned to their previous posts on my application.

Here is my code so far:

Models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='media')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes= models.IntegerField(default=0)
    dislikes= models.IntegerField(default=0)
    title = tagulous.models.SingleTagField(initial="test1, test2, test3")
    season = tagulous.models.TagField(
        autocomplete_view='tags_season_autocomplete'
    )
```

Views.py

```
class PostListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'core/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = PAGINATION_COUNT

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        all_users = []
        data_counter = Post.objects.values('author')\
            .annotate(author_count=Count('author'))\
            .order_by('-author_count')[:6]
        
        for aux in data_counter:
            all_users.append(User.objects.filter(pk=aux['author']).first())
     
        data['preference'] = Preference.objects.all()
        # print(Preference.objects.get(user= self.request.user))
        data['all_users'] = all_users
        print(all_users, file=sys.stderr)
        return data

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
   
        qs = Follow.objects.filter(user=user)
        follows = [user]
        
        for obj in qs:
            follows.append(obj.follow_user)
      
        return Post.objects.filter(author__in=follows).filter(season__name__in=['Winter']).order_by('-date_posted')
```

At the moment as seen in the last line of my Views.py file, I have managed to filter my Post Feed view based on manually defining the tag name (Although my goal here is to "get" all the tags from the "Posts" in which the user has created in the past and in return, filter the user's post feed based on the tags he has previously assigned to his or her previous posts on the application.

Any suggestions or pointers would be most appreciated!

(I have been referencing this source for ideas with forming a solution to my challenge - https://radiac.net/projects/django-tagulous/documentation/models/tagged_models/)

Thank you :-)

**UPDATE:**

So after a little more digging in to Tagulous, I have managed to change the last line of my views.py file to this:

`return Post.objects.filter(author__in=follows).filter(season__author=self.request.user).order_by('-date_posted')`

It's still not quite right as I am now receiving an error which says, "Cannot query  must be an instance of Tagulous_Post_season"`

Could anyone suggest a method of what would be the most suitable way to create the instance?

Thanks!